# Pinescript - background color "repaints" when the candle closes

Tags: signals, pine-script, price, candlestick-chart

I´m kinda new to scripting, So the thing is I set this tiny script to color the background when the candle crosses over the price of the laste candle, which works fine when that happens.

But if the price retracts and closes lower of the previous candle the coloring dissapears. How can I leave the background painted, even if the price retracts?

[image: backgroud repaints]

```
//@version=5
strategy(title="Crossup", calc_on_every_tick=true, overlay=true)

closeHigher = (close > high[1])
bgcolor(color=closeHigher ? color.rgb(6, 46, 8, 56) : na)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case, you don't want to use `close`. Instead, you should use `high`. Once current bar's `high` is higher than the previous bar's `high`, there is no way for that condition to become `false`. `high` will not go any lower, it can only go even higher :)

```
//@version=5
strategy(title="Crossup", calc_on_every_tick=true, overlay=true)

closeHigher = (high> high[1])
bgcolor(color=closeHigher ? color.rgb(6, 46, 8, 56) : na)
```